# PHP page doesn't load the data from my MySQL database on 123-reg

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to setup a connection to my MySql database via a php page which is hosted on 123-reg. The PHP page is "http://domainName.biz/android_connect/get_all_bars.php" which at the moment the page comes up blank?

The code for that page is as follows:

```
// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM pubbar");

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["pubbar"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $pubbar = array();
    $pubbar["Pubbar_ID"] = $row["Pubbar_ID"];
    $pubbar["Pubbar_Name"] = $row["Pubbar_Name"];
    $pubbar["Pubbar_AddressLine1"] = $row["Pubbar_AddressLine1"];
    $pubbar["Pubbar_AddressLine2"] = $row["Pubbar_AddressLine2"];
    $pubbar["Pubbar_LocationID"] = $row["Pubbar_LocationID"];
    $pubbar["Pubbar_Postcode"] = $row["Pubbar_Postcode"];
    $pubbar["Pubbar_Latitude"] = $row["Pubbar_Latitude"];
    $pubbar["Pubbar_Longitude"] = $row["Pubbar_Longitude"];
    $pubbar["Pubbar_TypeID"] = $row["Pubbar_TypeID"];
    $pubbar["Pubbar_DateCreated"] = $row["Pubbar_DateCreated"];
    $pubbar["Pubbar_DateModified"] = $row["Pubbar_DateModified"];

    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["pubbar"], $pubbar);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No bars found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
```

This code works on my local WAMP server on my PC

As you can see at the top it connect to another PHP page called "db_connect.php" and the code for that is below:

```
class DB_CONNECT {

// constructor
function __construct() {
    // connecting to database
    $this->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {
    // closing db connection
    $this->close();
}

/**
 * Function to connect with database
 */
function connect() {
    // import database connection variables
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

    // Connecting to mysql database
    $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

    // Selecing database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

    // returing connection cursor
    return $con;
}

/**
 * Function to close db connection
 */
function close() {
    // closing db connection
    mysql_close();
}

}
```

Again this work on my local WAMP server database. This also connects to another PHP page called "db_config.php" and the code for that is below:

```
<?php
/*
 * All database connection variables
 */

define('DB_USER', "<USER>"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', "<PASSWORD>"); // db password (mention your db         password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', "<DATABASE>"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "cust-mysql-X-X"); // db server

?>
```

As mentioned I have a wamp server setup for testing usage and all this functions as expected through that. However now I wish to put it on my server here, so it is all permanently accessible for my portfolio Android application and the get_all_bars.php page is coming up blank. I've messed around and changed code where I thought it might need changing but unfortunately the page still comes up blank. I have spoke with them before and the config data i.e username, password etc is all correct but I cannot figure out what might be wrong in the rest of this code.

Comment: Turn on error reporting, then you will get a nice helpful error message, rather than a blank page

Comment: I take it using ` <customErrors mode="off"/>` ? As this is in my web config but but the page is still blank

Comment: https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Web-Hosting/how-to-enable-error-reporting-on-the-123-reg-web-hosting-packages-5068/

Comment: Thanks Steve I wasn't aware of this. I will have a look

Comment: This has been caused by my hosting being a Windows OS hosting and not a Linux based hosting. Thanks for the error info Steve, would not have found that out other wise

Comment: Glad you have found the fault